# CI job failing with error - Unable to execute Cobertura. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=7, Argument list too long

Tags: cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

Here is the complete error failed to execute goal `org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument` (default) on project besinapp:

`Unable to execute Cobertura. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=7, Argument list too long`

I am using `Cobertura 2.6`

Is anyone facing this issue ?

Here is complete stack trace of the Cobertura plugin issue.

> 11:31:36 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default) on project besinapp: Unable to execute Cobertura. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=7, Argument list too long -> [Help 1] 11:31:36 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.6:instrument (default) on project besinapp: Unable to execute Cobertura. 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:364) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:198) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158) 11:31:36 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 11:31:36 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 11:31:36 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 11:31:36 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) 11:31:36 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute Cobertura. 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.AbstractTask.executeJava(AbstractTask.java:244) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.InstrumentTask.execute(InstrumentTask.java:139) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.CoberturaInstrumentMojo.execute(CoberturaInstrumentMojo.java:162) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106) 11:31:36 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208) 11:31:36 ... 23 more 11:31:36 Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process. 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute(Commandline.java:656) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:144) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:107) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.AbstractTask.executeJava(AbstractTask.java:240) 11:31:36 ... 27 more 11:31:36 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=7, Argument list too long 11:31:36 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047) 11:31:36 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617) 11:31:36 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528) 11:31:36 at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute(Commandline.java:636) 11:31:36 ... 30 more 11:31:36 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long 11:31:36 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) 11:31:36 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:186) 11:31:36 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130) 11:31:36 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028) 11:31:36 ... 33 more

Comment: I too have same question.